# How do I know if bucardo making master to master or master to slave replication

Tags: postgresql, bucardo

I've created a sync via Bucardo for the first time using the following command:

```
bucardo add sync test_sync relgroup=copying_herd dbs=source_test_db:source,dest_test_db:target onetimecopy=2
```

Now I want to be sure if I made a master-to-slave replication or master-to-master. How could one check which kind of replication bucardo is making?